# How to save barcodeScanner result to localStorage in cordova plugin barcodeScanner

Tags: javascript, cordova, barcode-scanner

I got one tutorial from [SAP](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-56113) that works for barcodeScanner wildabeast cordova plugin.
From the tutorial it had an index.html itself for call the function. then i implant it in my app's index.html and the code is like this:

```
<div data-role="content" style="text-align: center">
    <h3 style="color: blue">Selamat datang.</h3>
    <button onclick="scan()">Scan QR Code</button> <!-- call function scan() from barcodescanner.js -->
    <a href="#manual" class="ui-btn">Masukkan Kode</a> 
      <div id="scan_results"></div> <!-- unknown -->
</div> <!-- /contain -->
```

and barcodescanner.js is like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
    function init() {
    }

    function scan() {
        log("scanning");
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(scanSuccessCallback, scanErrorCallback);
    }

    function scanSuccessCallback(result) {
        log(JSON.stringify(result));
        /*
        alert("We got a barcode\n" +
        "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
        "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
        "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
         */
    }

    function scanErrorCallback(error) {
        alert("Scanning failed: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }

    function encode() {
        log("encoding");
        if (device.platform == "Android") {  //Not supported on iOS
            var stringToEncode = "http://www.sap.com";
            cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode(cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, stringToEncode, encodeSuccessCallback, encodeErrorCallback);
        }
        else {
            log("Encoding is not supported on iOS.  See https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/issues/106");  
        }
    }

    function encodeSuccessCallback(result) {
        log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }

    function encodeErrorCallback(error) {
        alert("Encoding failed: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }

    function log(line) {
        var results = document.getElementById("scan_results");
        results.innerHTML+= "<br>" + line;
    }
```

i suppose to save the scan result to LocalStorage and the result is not shown in the app. Can someone help me to do it like that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage is really just an object that behaves like any other. Choose a property name and either use the getters and setters like:

```
localStorage.setItem('item1', '8383838838');

localStorage.getItem('item1');
```

Or simply:

```
localStorage.item1 = '8383838838';
```

Note that if you want to store an object in it you can, but you will have to stringify it first.

Not that this should be a problem with modern browsers, but before using this api, always check to see if LocalStorage exists first.

Comment: oh, i see. from what i see 'item1' is the localstorage name and the number is the value. and from my code in javascript the result from scan is 'result.text'. is it right? is it already string type or not? for my app the qrcode contect is a code with string type.

Comment: It seems that if you try to save a number to localstorage, it will automatically convert it to a string, and if its already a string, you dont need to worry about it. However this is not so with objects. You will have to serialize it first.